# Why is finding the minimum of $\phi(x)={1\over2}x^TAx-x^Tb$ equivalent to finding the solution of $Ax=b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, quadratic-programming

Let $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ be symmetric and invertible, and $b \in \Bbb R^n$. Why is finding the minimum of $$\phi(x)={1\over2}x^TAx-x^Tb$$ equivalent to finding the solution of $Ax=b$?

$$Ax=b \implies Ax-b=0\nRightarrow\text{?}{1\over2}x^TAx-x^Tb=0\text{ is minimal}$$

The other implication is also obscure to me.

Comment: You may try to show that $\phi(A^{-1}b)\le\phi(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Do you have any hypotheses on $A$ (like $A$ symmetric) ?

Comment: Yep, A has to be symmetric

Comment: @Arthur With $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&-1\\1&1 \end{pmatrix}$, $A$ is invertible but I think that the claim is false.

Comment: Note that if $\phi$ is indefinite, then there is no minimum. The solution of $A x = b$ is then a saddle point.

Comment: You also require $A$ to be positive definite.

Comment: Basic derivative calculus on a matrix equation.  Partial derivatives, of course.  You can think of $\frac{d}{d\vec x} \phi(\vec x) = A\vec x - b$.  And setting equal to $\vec 0$ gives rise to your desired equation. Finding a solution for $A\vec x=\vec b$ is finding the optimal point for $\phi(\vec x)$.

Comment: A naive approach that requires no calculus: Complete the square to transform $\frac12x^TAx-x^Tb$ into $\frac12(x-A^{-1}b)^TA(x-A^{-1}b)$ plus a constant. After this, you will also require positive definiteness of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

You have:
\begin{align}
\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)&={1\over2}(x+h)^TA(x+h)-(x+h)^Tb-\left({1\over2}x^TAx-x^Tb \right)\\
&={1\over2}\left(  h^T A x+x^T A h\right) -h^T b +{1 \over 2} h^T A h
\end{align}
so if $x$ is an extremum then $\forall h$:
$${1\over2}\left(  h^T A x+x^T A h\right) -h^T b ={1\over2}\left(  h^T A x+h^T A^T x\right) -h^T b=h^T \left(\frac{A^T+A}{2}x-b \right)=0$$
i.e:
$$\left(\frac{A^T+A}{2}x-b \right)=0$$
which gives the desired result if $A$ is symmetric.

For the other implication if $A$ is positive the previous calculation gives the result but if $A$ is not positive this is not true: for example in dimension $1$ with $A=(-1)$ you obtain a maximum and not a minimum.

Comment: why if x is an extremum  ${1\over2}\left(  h^T A x+x^T A h\right) -h^T b=0$ ?

Comment: Because if it isn't then it is the smallest non-zero order so near $h=0$ we have:
$$\phi(x+h)-\phi(x) \sim L(h)$$
where $L(h)={1\over2}\left(  h^T A x+x^T A h\right) -h^T b$.

In particular $\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)$ as the same sign than $L(h)$ which is linear so there is no way it is always $\geq 0$ near $h=0$, so there is a contradiction.

Comment: It is exactly the same as the argument why if $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ as a minimum on $x_0$ then $f'(x_0)=0$ (in fact $L$ is the differential of $\phi$ at the point $x$).

Comment: Yes but first the left side of the equality is not the derivative (here gradient because $\Bbb R^n\mapsto\Bbb R$) and second why for all $h$? Shouldn't it be just when $h$ goes to zero?

Comment: Yes but the argument with the derivative is also correct for the gradient (for example you can say that following any direction this is a local minimum). And yes it is when $h \to 0$ but by linearity you can prove that this is for all $h$.

Comment: No I meant ${1\over2}(h^TAx+x^TAh)-h^Tb\ne\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)$ Did you not write $+{1\over2}h^TAh$ on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Are all eigenvalues of $A$ positive? Otherwise if $A$ has negative eigenvalues, then finding the minimum will NOT be equivalent to finding the solution to $Ax = b$

Assuming that all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive: The partial derivatives of each component of the objective function is 0 at the vector $x$ satisfying $Ax = b$. This is a simple calculation.

Comment: Is minimizing any function with derivative $0$ at $A^{-1}b$ enough?

Comment: No it is not. All eigenvalues of $A$ have to be positive. (For some reason I read $A$ positive-definite). Otherwise the minimum of $A$ will come at a boundary point (assuming that we are optimizing over a compact set)

Comment: Making an edit per the comment

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix is positive definite, then the minimum will occur when $\nabla_x \phi(x) = 0$.

Just doing out the math we have

$$
\begin{align*}
 \nabla_x \phi(x) &= \nabla_x \left(\frac{1}{2} x^TAx - b^Tx\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \nabla_x \left(x^TAx\right) - \nabla_x(b^Tx)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(A +A^T\right)x - b \\
&= Ax -b  \qquad   // \quad A = A^T\\
\end{align*}
$$
Setting this gradient to 0 we have the optimality condition stated. As others have stressed, this only means that $x^\star$ satisfying this condition is a stationary point unless you know $A$ is symmetric

The gradients used in line 3 are common enough that they should probably be committed to memory. The gradient of $b^Tx$ can be derived by writing out the dot product as $\sum_{i=1}^n b_ix_i$. Or you can just remember that it's analagous to the scalar case $\frac{d}{dx} (bx) = b$

The gradient of the quadratic is a little more effort to derive but can be done similarly by writing out the matrix multiplication and just taking partial derivatives
$$x^TAx = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n x_ix_jA_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n A_{ii}x_i^2 + 2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n A_{ij}x_ix_j$$

The fact that $\nabla_x x^TAx = 2Ax$ when $A$ is symmetric is easily remembered by analogy with the scalar case where $\frac{d}{dx} (ax^2) = 2ax$